# Facebook-lint-error "Could not retrieve data from URL"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an issue using the OpenGraph on my website (I don't get images or content when I share the URL listed below). When I test [my URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.plus-wuustwezel.be) with the debugger, I get the famous `Could not retrieve data from URL`-error.

I've been searching for solutions on the internet and possible causes could be corrupt code (unvalid according to the validator) or missing `meta`-tags.
I've fixed all the errors, but still, the Facebook debugger can't get data from the URL.

So maybe, it has something to do with my website structure. I have an `index.php`-file and a `content`directory where I include all the content:

```
<div class="content_container">
    <?php
        // Include the page content
        include_once('content/' . $_PAGE . '.php');
    ?>
</div>
```

So my URL's look like `www.mysite.com/index.php?page=news&article=12`
Could this have anything to do with my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [character encoding string is incorrect](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plus-wuustwezel.be%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0#fatal-errors).

Add a dash between "ISO" and "8" on line 6 of your generated source:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had changed the App settings within Facebook and I guess I hadn't refreshed the page I was developing. If anyone else gets this error after they have changed their App settings, simply try refreshing your browser and try again. Perhaps it just takes time for these changes to propagate throughout Facebook, after a matter of around an error with NO code changes this issue no longer appeared for me.